# WMI Call to retrieve Physical Serial Number on HDD's

Tags: hard-drive, wmi, wmic, serial-number

I'm trying to write a script that incorporates a retrieved Drive Serial Number for a report. So far I've just been trying to get a WMI call or really anything to even retrieve it in the first place

```
WMIC PATH CIM_PhysicalMedia
```

works on some computers but not in the WinPE environment I need it to work on. I keep getting: `Invalid XML Content.`

Every command I try, I use both `CIM_PhysicalMedia` and `Win32_PhysicalMedia` and neither work when it doesn't work.

What's funny is, the system it works on is Windows 7 Pro but it doesn't work on another PC with the same OS! Am I missing a dll or something?

Please help! Again this is supposed to work in a WinPE environment. I do not know the version but I do know that WMIC works normally.

Please help!!

PS I have experience with simple WMI calls like `wmic bios get serialnumber` and the like but I have never messed with anything this apparently complex.

Comment: Have you Tried `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber`

Answer (score 1):

#### Am I missing a dll or something?

```
WMIC PATH CIM_PhysicalMedia
```

> I keep getting: `Invalid XML Content.`

You could be missing a hotfix:

> This issue occurs because **the XML parser treats the control characters that are included in the serial number of some drives as invalid**.

Try installing the hotfix available from the source link below ("Hotfix Download Available" button)

---

#### "Invalid XML content" error message when you run a WMIC command in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2

> **SYMPTOMS**
>
> Consider the following scenario. You connect a USB flash drive to a
>   computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2. You try
>   to run one of the following Windows Management Instrumentation
>   Command-line (WMIC) tool commands to query the hard disk drives on the
>   computer:
>
> ```
> wmic diskdrive get *
> wmic diskdrive get serialNumber
> ```
>
> In this scenario, you receive an error message that resembles the
>   following:
>
> ```
> Invalid XML content
> ```
>
> **CAUSE**
>
> This issue occurs because the XML parser treats the control characters
>   that are included in the serial number of some drives as invalid.
>   Therefore, the XML parser cannot parse content that includes these
>   control characters. This behavior causes valid results for other
>   drives to be displayed incorrectly, together with the behavior that is
>   mentioned in the "Symptoms" section.
>
> **RESOLUTION**
>
> A supported hotfix is available from Microsoft. However, this hotfix
>   is intended to correct only the problem that is described in this
>   article. Apply this hotfix only to systems that are experiencing the
>   problem described in this article. This hotfix might receive
>   additional testing. Therefore, if you are not severely affected by
>   this problem, we recommend that you wait for the next software update
>   that contains this hotfix.
>
> If the hotfix is available for download, there is a "Hotfix download
>   available" section at the top of this Knowledge Base article. If this
>   section does not appear, contact Microsoft Customer Service and
>   Support to obtain the hotfix.

Source ["Invalid XML content" error message when you run a WMIC command in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2664203)